# @Value on R2dbc table fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

Given the following entity/table defined in a Spring/KotlinCoroutines project.

```kotlin
@Table("workers")
data class Worker(
    @Id
    val id: UUID? = null,

    @Column(value = "photo")
    var photo: String? = null,

    // see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/449
    @Transient
    @Value("#{root.photo!=null}")
    val hasPhoto: Boolean = false
)
```

The `hasPhoto` field does not map to a table field. I follow the R2dbc official reference doc and use a Spring EL to evaluate the EL result as value of this field.

But when I test this `hasPhoto`, it always returns false even I set the photo to a nonnull string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from the Spring guys, `@Value` here only can access the projection.